# gulp+webpack-stream+coffee-loaderでcoffeescriptのエラーをハンドリングできません。

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

gulp+webpackでcoffeescriptをjavascriptへ変換する際にcoffeeの書式エラー等でビルドに失敗した時にgulp-notify等で通知を出したいのですが、gulpの`.on('error', function(){})`でエラーを取得できません。

必要最低限の`gulpfile.coffee`を以下のように記述してみたのですが、coffee/common.coffeeへ`if a? b :: c`のようなエラーを起こすコードを入れてビルドしてもターミナルへcoffee-lint-loaderの出力がでるだけで`[webpack] build error!`が出力されないようです。
webpackのコールバック関数でチェックもしたのですが、最終的なerrの内容がcommon.coffeeのビルド結果に関係なく`null`になっているようです。

webpack内のNormalModules.jsのdoBuild()内ではerrの内容が格納されているのでスタックトレースを追いかけてみたのですが、errの内容が`null`になる理由がわかりませんでした。
loader側のエラーの場合にエラーハンドリングができない原因は分かりますでしょうか。

#### gulpfile.coffee

```
gulp    = require 'gulp'
gutil   = require 'gulp-util'
webpack = require 'webpack-stream'

dest = './build'
src  = './coffee'

config =
  entry:
    common: src + '/common.coffee'
  output:
    filename: '[name].js'
  resolve:
    modulesDirectories: [ 'node_modules' ]
    extensions: [ "", ".js", ".coffee", ".webpack.js", ".web.js" ]
  module:
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.coffee$/, loader: "coffee-loader" }
    ]
    preLoaders: [
      { test: /\.coffee$/, loader: "coffee-lint-loader" }
    ]

gulp.task 'coffee', ->
  gulp.src src
    .pipe webpack config
    .on 'error', ->
      gutil.log '[webpack] build error!'
    .pipe gulp.dest dest
```

参考までにテストした環境はnode.js v4.0.0に以下のnpmパッケージを入れた物となっています。

```
  "dependencies": {
    "coffee-lint-loader": "0.0.1",
    "coffee-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "coffee-script": "^1.10.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.6",
    "webpack-stream": "^2.1.0"
  }
```

---

### 解決方法

`webpack-stream`をパイプラインで実行する際に第3引数へコールバック関数を設定し、`stats`からerrorsを取得する事でloadersのエラー内容を確認することが出来ました。

このerrorsの内容の取得方法が2種類あるようです。
一つは公式サイトの例に載っている`stats.toJson().errors`を使った方法、もう一つは`stats.compilation.errors`から変換前のログを取得する方法となります。

以下は公式サイトの`toJson()`を利用した簡単な例になります。

```
gulp.task 'coffee', ->
  gulp.src src
    .pipe webpack config, null, (error, stats) ->
      for err in stats.toJson().errors
        gutil.log '[webpack] ' + err.toString()
    .pipe gulp.dest dest
```

参考までに今回の解決方法を元に`gulp-notify`に対応させたタスクがこんな感じになりました。
ログのフォーマット修正等を行いたかったので`stats.compilation.errors`を元にゴチャゴチャと処理してます。
https://gist.github.com/sasrai/b38fbcaa0ad2bb53542c

Comment: 見落としていたんですがwebpackの公式サイトに[エラーハンドリング](http://webpack.github.io/docs/node.js-api.html#error-handling)の方法が書いてあったようです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

実際に出たエラーログの内容はありますか？`error`イベントで拾えない場合、[process.on('uncaughtException')など](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception)で例外を受信している可能性があります。つまるところ、使用しているモジュールが想定していない箇所で、エラーが発生しているのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 特にwebpackそのもののエラーログが出力されることなく例外も帰ってこないため、もしかしてと思いwebpackのコールバックで帰ってくるcompilationの内容を見なおしてみました。
その際にerrors配列へcoffee-lintの構文チェックエラーのログ内容が書かれているのを見つけることができました。
もう少し詳しく調べて解決方法を追記しておきます。